# How to run FTP script from batch file on Windows?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I'm trying to create a `.bat` file to delete all XML files on a certain FTP folder regardless of the date of the file. I've tried many scripts without any solution.

Many experts are talking about `.txt` file containing the below script, but to be quite honest I don't know how to execute it or even am if I am creating the file correctly or not.

All I need is to delete all the files on this container.

```
open ftp://xxxx.xxxx.net
myusername
mypassword
cd /bts/xxxx
mdelete *
quit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your FTP script looks ok. You just might want to replace `mdelete *` with `mdelete *.xml`, if there are also other files than `.xml` in the folder.

To actually run the script, run `ftp.exe` from your batch file like:

```
@echo off
echo Running FTP to delete XML files...
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

where `ftp.txt` is filename containing your FTP script (the one from your question).